# Pandas describe() function doesn't print anything on PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I'm studying the crash course by google, and I'm trying to run this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd

city_names = pd.Series(['San Francisco', 'San Jose', 'Sacramento'])
population = pd.Series([852469, 1015785, 485199])
cities = pd.DataFrame({ 'City name': city_names, 'Population': population })
cities['Area square miles'] = pd.Series([46.87, 176.53, 97.92])
cities['Population density'] = cities['Population'] / cities['Area square 
miles']
cities['Is wide and has saint name'] = (cities['Area square miles'] > 50) & 
cities['City name']\
    .apply(lambda name: name.startswith('San'))

cities.describe()
```

If I run that on the google online notebook, it prints a table with data..if I run that on my computer using pycharm, it doesn't print anything. That's should be the output:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On its own, `describe` does not print anything. It **returns** a dataframe.

From its [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

> **Returns**: summary: Series/DataFrame of summary statistics

Unlike PyCharm, the notebook you are using is wired to automatically print the return values of statements.

Change `cities.describe()` to `print(cities.describe())`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thank you man! Could you tell me the difference between .describe and .describe()? They print different things...

Comment: @Nicola `.describe` is a method, `.describe()` calls that method

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but they print different output if i wrote cities.describe and cities.describe()

Comment: @Nicola yes, of course, *because one simply references the method and the other calls the method and evaluates the result*